# NetworkX, How do I successfully catch network.exception.NetworkXError when node is not in the graph?

Tags: python, exception, networkx

When a node is not in the graph I get and exception error.  As I try to catch and handle it, I can't (so I must be doing something wrong).  How do I catch and handle `networkx.exception.NetworkXError`?

Here is the error:

`<snip>
    raise NetworkXError("The node %s is not in the digraph."%(n,))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node 33293542 is not in the digraph.`

Here is how I've tried to catch it and handle it:

```
try:
    path_len = nx.shortest_path_length(G,uNode, vNode)
except (nx.NetworkXNoPath, nx.exception.NetworkXError) as e:
    print e
    continue
```

I have also tried:

```
try:
        path_len = nx.shortest_path_length(G,uNode, vNode)
except (nx.NetworkXNoPath, KeyError) as e:
        print e
        continue
```

I maintain `uNode` and `vNode` in two lists, I could do a: `if v in target_nodes:`, but before I do that, I was wondering if there is an elegant way to handle this `NetworkX exception`?

Comment: Why can't you just do `if G.has_node(uNode) and G.has_node(vNode): path_len = nx.shortest_path_length(G,uNode, vNode)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're doing is ensuring you don't try to get the path length of a non-existent node then why not just use [`has_node`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.has_node.html):

```
if G.has_node(uNode) and G.has_node(vNode):
    path_len = nx.shortest_path_length(G,uNode, vNode)
```

**EDIT**

The following worked for me:

```
In [76]:    
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(2,3)
try:
    nx.shortest_path_length(G,0,1)
except nx.NetworkXError:
    print("not found")

not found
```

Comment: Your recommendation is a good work-around! But, why is one unable to handle that particular exception, is it an issue with NetworkX?

Comment: I don't know will investigate

Comment: it looks like the appropriate exception type should be `nx.NetworkXError`

Answer (score 3):

It should be `nx.exception.NetworkXError`, so:

```
import networkx as nx

try:
    nx.shortest_path_length(G,0,1)
except nx.exception.NetworkXError:
    print("not found")
```